Configuring Apache Tomcat for HTTPS
I have an App that uses HTTP rather than HTTPS.  For Security purposes, I need to switch to using HTTPS.  I'm using apache_tomcat9.0.87.linux.rrg.
We have a CA.  I have generated a Certificate from the CA (WebCA11 CRL / RSA 4096).  The file comes in .pfx format.  It's called MyHostname.pfx
I also downloaded the SHA2 Root CA (my terminology might be wrong) which gave me 2 files:
inhouse_root_CA_2_DER.crt
inhouse_root_CA_2_PEM.cer
The question I have is what do I do with these files?  I have little to no experience of using Certificates or Apache.  I'm well versed in using Linux though.
Thank you

If you are concerned about security, performance and capacity then put a reverse proxy in front of Tomcat (good app server, bad webserver) and terminate the SSL there.
